# Cannot get XmlReader to recognize (insignificant)?whitespace

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following example xml content for which I want to retain the whitespace between the two pairs of `<p>` elements. I would understand this to be *insignificant* whitespace.

```xml
<x>
  <p>Hello</p>

<p>How are you?</p></x>
```

```cs
XElement h = new XElement("x",
        new XElement("p", "Hello"),
        new XText("\n\n"),
        new XElement("p", "How are you?"));
```

The following code will output a single instance of `ws found`:

```cs
string p = "<x><p>Hello</p>\n\n<p>How are you?</p></x>";
StringReader sr = new StringReader(p);
    
XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(sr, new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreWhitespace = false });
    
while (r.Read())
{
    switch (r.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
            WriteLine("ws found");
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
            WriteLine("sws found");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I only get one output line because whitespace is normalized.

However, I want the same output using an XElement as the source rather than a string but below doesn't output anything:

```cs
XElement h = new XElement("x",
        new XElement("p", "Hello"),
        new XText("\n\n"),
        new XElement("p", "How are you?"));

XmlReader r = h.CreateReader();
    
while (r.Read())
{
    switch (r.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
            WriteLine("ws found");
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
            WriteLine("sws found");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I have tried including `r.Settings.IgnoreWhitespace = false;` but it doesn't help and is the default anyway.

Can anyone shed a light on how I can read and process the whitespace using `XmlReader`?

Comment: Is it perhaps being notified as a Text event rather than a Whitespace event?

Comment: @MichaelKay No, when I step through in debug the Reader actually seems to skip over them.

Comment: @MichaelKay Well, it always pays to double-check others' suggestions! You were dead right, they are classified as `XmlNodeType.Text`. Don't know how I missed that. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the whitespace text nodes are being notified as `XmlNodeType.Text`.